# zooming on a tkinter canvas with lines created by live data

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, zooming, android-livedata

I am new to Tkinter and trying to figure out how to be able to zoom in and out on a canvas without messing up the drawn lines created by live data. Every second a new line is drawn and is supposed to be connected to the previous one, but if I zoom in on the canvas the next line that will be drawn is not connected to the previous one. It seems like all the lines are drawn based on some window coordinates (which are consistent no matter how much I zoom in or out), instead of being based on the canvas itself. I want to be able to both zoom in and zoom out as much as I want and still see a line being drawn from the upper left corner of the canvas to the bottom right corner of the canvas. I have tried to provide some code to make it easier to understand.

```
import tkinter as tk
import threading
import time

root = tk.Tk()
pressed = False
flag_run = False

GRID_W = 500
GRID_H = 500

def thread_entry(name):
    print("<starting thread>")
    i = 0
    j = 0
    while flag_run:
        time.sleep(1)
        canvas.create_line(i, j, i+1, j+1, fill="red")
        i += 1
        j += 1
    print("<ending thread>")

def start():
    global flag_run
    flag_run = True
    global thread
    thread = threading.Thread(target=thread_entry, args=(1,))
    thread.start()

def stop():
    global flag_run
    if flag_run is True:
        flag_run = False
        global thread
        thread.join(timeout=0.1)

# move
def move_start(event):
    canvas.scan_mark(event.x, event.y)

def move_move(event):
    canvas.scan_dragto(event.x, event.y, gain=1)

# move
def pressed2(event):
    global pressed
    pressed = not pressed
    canvas.scan_mark(event.x, event.y)

def move_move2(event):
    if pressed:
        canvas.scan_dragto(event.x, event.y, gain=1)

# windows zoom
def zoomer(event):
    if (event.delta > 0):
        canvas.scale("all", event.x, event.y, 1.1, 1.1)
    elif (event.delta < 0):
        canvas.scale("all", event.x, event.y, 0.9, 0.9)
    canvas.configure(scrollregion = canvas.bbox("all"))

def zooming_in(event):
    canvas.scale("all", event.x, event.y, 1.1, 1.1)

def zooming_out(event):
    canvas.scale("all", event.x, event.y, 0.9, 0.9)

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=GRID_W, height=GRID_H, background="white")
canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

for i in range(GRID_W//10 + 1):
    canvas.create_line(i*10, 0, i*10, GRID_H, fill="#c9c9c9")

for j in range(GRID_H//10 + 1):
    canvas.create_line(0, j*10, GRID_W, j*10, fill="#c9c9c9")

canvas.create_line(GRID_W // 2, 0, GRID_W // 2, GRID_H, fill="black", width=2)
canvas.create_line(0, GRID_H // 2, GRID_W, GRID_H // 2, fill="black", width=2)

canvas.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", move_start)
canvas.bind("<B1-Motion>", move_move)

canvas.bind("<ButtonPress-2>", pressed2)
canvas.bind("<Motion>", move_move2)

zoom_in = tk.Button(root, text="+")
zoom_in.grid(row=1, column=0)
zoom_in.bind("<Button-1>", zooming_in)

zoom_out = tk.Button(root, text="-")
zoom_out.grid(row=1, column=1)
zoom_out.bind("<Button-1>", zooming_out)

button = tk.Button(root, text="Start", command = start)
button.grid(row=2, column=0)

button_s = tk.Button(root, text="Stopp", command = stop)
button_s.grid(row=2, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

I appreciate all the help and guidance I can get!

Answer (score 0):

try stopping the flag_run while you hit the start button (zooming_in(event)) and continue when done zooming.
try remembering where the line was, and keep logging the data while you zoom in and out so you are not missing any values as you currently do.